# ShouldI replace setTimeout with node schedule in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I want to stop players from entering a raffle starting from 11:55pm - 11:59pm every thursday, so I have to make sure the route for entering the raffle at this particular time is block. I decided to use node-schedule for every seconds to see what the result would look like, but I was able to access the route. I dont know if node-schedule is suitable for this kind of thing or if I should use a setTimeout that runs every seconds in the server so I can check if its time to restrict players.

My questions are:

1. Pls what approach do you think would be the best to achieve this?
2. Will scheduling a job or using a setTimeout that run every seconds/minutes in my server breaks it.

Here is the code I wrote for restricting user from an endpoint at some particular seconds, but it is not working.

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  schedule.scheduleJob("1-20 * * * * *", async () => {
    res.status(400)
  })
  res.status(200).json({ msg: "You're in!!" })
})
```

Comment: Two ways, either crontab, that means making a node script that is executable every thursday at 11:55.
Or add a condition in that app.get('/'...) code, check if new date() is between thursday 11:55 and 11h59 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a functions to check if the date is in that range

```js
const isClosed = (date) => date.getDay() === 4 && date.getHours() === 23 && date.getMinutes()>= 55 && date.getMinutes()<= 59

console.log(isClosed(new Date('2022-08-25 23:55:01')))
```

and then you can use a middleware to block the request like this

```
const isClosedMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const date = new Date()
  if(isClosed(date)){
    res.status(400)
  } else {
     next()
  }
}

app.get("/", isClosedMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ msg: "You're in!!" })
})
```